# Помогите найти ошибку в js

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, в чем ошибся. Нужно взять число из элемента `span`, удалить все пробелы, прибавить другое число и снова поставить пробелы (разделители разрядов).

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    var text = jQuery('span').text().split(' ').join('');

    text = Number(text) + 1;
    text = text.toLocaleString('ru-RU');

    jQuery('span').text(text);
  }, 1000);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sdjtzxao/

На втором шаге в `span` записывается строка "Не число".

Comment: Попробуйте убрать "text = text.toLocaleString('ru-RU');"

Comment: @AlexNem, тогда потеряет `снова поставить пробелы (разделители разрядов)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text.toLocaleString('ru-RU')` вставляет не обычный пробел, а неразрывный (который `&nbsp;` в HTML). Поэтому `split(' ')` его не видит.

Проще просто поменять `split(' ').join('')` на `replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')` который оставит в строке только цифры.

```js
var text = jQuery('span').text().replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
```

Либо хранить число отдельно от его представления.
Например в атрибутах `data-...` https://jsfiddle.net/byzeatmh/

Comment: от себя добавлю, что пробел может иметь код 20 (стандартный), либо 160 (неразрывный).

Comment: Там есть ещё пяток разных пробелов =)

Comment: Вот так красиво =) https://jsfiddle.net/dnsebvwf/

Comment: зарплата за день, можно смотреть до бесконечности )

Comment: сплитить можно по `/\s/` там все пробелы учитываются

Comment: @Grundy ага. Впрочем я считаю что значение вообще нужно хранить отдельно от представления. А то завтра кто-то захочет что бы там было написано «три тысячи один» или придёт локализатор и скажет, что мы запускаем сайт на арабском и удачи парсить `٣٬٠٠٢`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, нет предела совершенству ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо. Я храню значение отдельно от представления, это, разумеется, самый правильный вариант. Но было интересно узнать, в чем проблема - о неразрывном пробеле я не подумал.